# what does it mean pointer to own Class&

Tags: c++

I understand that pointer has reference to object? In order not to duplicate it

```
class A 
{
    A(){};
}
A *ptrA;
```

1. why do we need a pointer to own class?
2. how does it work?

Comment: `ptrA` is pointer of **type** `A`, not _pointer to own class_.

Comment: how actually does it work?

Comment: The idea of _ownership_ usually refers to an API contract that specifies who is responsible for keeping a record of and ultimately deallocating an _object_. (Not a _class_, types don’t have an object representation (reflection) in C++.) That said, using raw pointers is mostly a bad idea; use smart pointers instead to document ownership and ownership transfers.

Comment: A pointer variable is just a variable that contains an address to somewhere in memory. That's it.

Comment: It works **the same way** as **any other kind** of pointer. (Well, except pointers to member functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `ptrA` is `A *` which mean `class A` pointer, so, `ptrA` is pointer of type `class A`.
It can hold the reference of memory of object of type `A`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    void test() {
        std::cout << "test() member function" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* ptrA = new A(); // Dynamic allocation of object of type A
    ptrA->test();
    delete ptrA;       // Delete the object created dynamically

    A objA;            // object of type A created locally

    ptrA = &objA;      // ptrA assigned address of object objA
    ptrA->test();

    return 0;
}
```